# v-for returns empty on Vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for

This is my first project on Vue.Js. I am not able to display my nested object using `v-for`. It prints out empty list when `v-for` is used on `{{element.fist_name}}`.

Below is my code on **jsfiddle** .

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/yeh9cdap/11/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/27sx8aLp/

Answer (score 1):

At final v-for you have element:

```
"Person": {
                "id": 1,
                "first_name": "David",
                "last_name": "Sew",
                "email": "david@gmail.com",
 }
```

it iterate for each property, you see it if you change to:

```
 <div class="list-group-item item" v-for="element in yahoo.Person" v-bind:key="element.id">
     {{element}}
 </div>
```

if yo want to display you dont need to make the last v-for, just:

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-for="reservation in teamByTime2" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
   <div v-for="yahoo in reservation.Reservation_people" v-bind:key="yahoo.id" >    
     {{yahoo.Person.first_name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```